# Add space to text field in input

Tags: css, input, text

How can I add right space between the text field in this input and the input border? (see the image) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or8Sr.png)

I used

```
input{
text-indent: 2em;}
```

for the left side, but I wanna know how to do the same on the right side

Answer (score 0):

Use `padding` left/right

```css
input {
  padding: 0 2em;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="blablablablablablablablablablablabla"></input>
</form>
```